# How i can add more field when create payment with connect account stripe

Tags: javascript, laravel, stripe-payments

I have a question about stripe's connect account. How i can add more field (etc name, email,..) when create payment
I try to add field `defaultValues` > `billingDetails` > `name,email,..`

[Here is document:]
(https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_payment_element),

This is layout when i call payment
[image]
i call api to stripe to get all charge, and the picture is the field i want to add more:
[image]
This is my code:

```
const stripeAccount = document.body.getAttribute('data-stripe-account');
const amount = document.body.getAttribute('data-stripe-amount');
const userrequest = document.body.getAttribute('data-u-r');
const returnURL = document.getElementById('URL').value;
const data = {user_request: userrequest, stripeAccount: stripeAccount, amount: amount };
let elements;
const stripe = Stripe("pk_test_51ObgQ7AapkrJHjBL5v8Q...Au17hotn4NOaI6FITTVH84auC00Cq4IfMCd",
{
  stripeAccount: stripeAccount,
}
);

initialize();
checkStatus();

document
  .querySelector("#payment-form")
  .addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);

// Fetches a payment intent and captures the client secret
async function initialize() {
  const { clientSecret } = await fetch("/stripe/acceptPayment", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ data }),
  }).then((r) => r.json());

  elements = stripe.elements({ clientSecret });

  const billingDetails = {
    name: "messi lionel"
  }

  const paymentElementOptions = {
    layout: "tabs",
    defaultValues: {
      billingDetails: billingDetails
    }
  };

  const paymentElement = elements.create("payment", paymentElementOptions);
  paymentElement.mount("#payment-element");
}
async function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setLoading(true);

  const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
    elements,
    confirmParams: {
      return_url: returnURL,
    },
  });

  if (error.type === "card_error" || error.type === "validation_error") {
    showMessage(error.message);
  } else {
    showMessage("An unexpected error occurred.");
  }

  setLoading(false);
}

async function checkStatus() {
  const clientSecret = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
    "payment_intent_client_secret"
  );

  if (!clientSecret) {
    return;
  }

  const { paymentIntent } = await stripe.retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret);

  switch (paymentIntent.status) {
    case "succeeded":
      showMessage("Payment succeeded!");
      break;
    case "processing":
      showMessage("Your payment is processing.");
      break;
    case "requires_payment_method":
      showMessage("Your payment was not successful, please try again.");
      break;
    default:
      showMessage("Something went wrong.");
      break;
  }
}

// ------- UI helpers -------

function showMessage(messageText) {
  const messageContainer = document.querySelector("#payment-message");

  messageContainer.classList.remove("hidden");
  messageContainer.textContent = messageText;

  setTimeout(function () {
    messageContainer.classList.add("hidden");
    messageContainer.textContent = "";
  }, 4000);
}

// Show a spinner on payment submission
function setLoading(isLoading) {
  if (isLoading) {
    // Disable the button and show a spinner
    document.querySelector("#submit").disabled = true;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.remove("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.add("hidden");
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#submit").disabled = false;
    document.querySelector("#spinner").classList.add("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#button-text").classList.remove("hidden");
  }
}
```

I tried following the document but without success.

Answer (score 0):

you should integrate the `billing` mode [Address Element](https://stripe.com/docs/elements/address-element) alongside with the payment element to collect the billing address from your customer.